# Calendar view Event Transition

Tags: ios, custom-view

I am working on Calendar view customization. I'm using [this](https://github.com/jumartin/Calendar) library.

I want this kind of uiview Added in to this Calendar. Actually I am able to add event by long press (as you can see in below gif), but I want to add those two dot(button) to resize the event view and change the event timings respectively.

Output we required as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: Will you share the demo? Bcause the library showing some error of file missing. Please share this I will check it and return back with solution

Comment: @JeckyModi just re install pods it will work.

Comment: I try it but nothing works.

Comment: @jecky modi, please update pod before running the project.